# Use a stored procedure parameter in a SQL Server window function to specify ROWS

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to use an input parameter to specify a number of rows in a window function in SQL Server 2014 Standard, but am getting an error because it's expecting an actual integer value.  It would be ideal to parameterize the procedure because different ranges of non-contiguous days are needed for a moving average calculation.  A simple, general example would be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MovingAverage @days INTEGER
AS

SELECT
    saledate,
    item,
    saleprice,
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY saledate) > @days 
    THEN AVG(saleprice) OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY saledate ROWS BETWEEN @days PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) 
    ELSE NULL END [MA]
FROM transactions
```

I could brute force a solution but am curious if I'm missing something to keep it simple.  Any ideas?

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: 2014 Standard Edition

Comment: And thanks for the pointer, Sean.  I'll get more info together for this example soon.